# How to use apache commons download

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I've just downloaded `apache commons-lang3-3.2.1` source and binary because I want to try out their Fraction class.

My first question is how to find the relevant file to add to the build path in Eclipse?

My second question is whether to use binary or source?

I've tried looking in both but I can only see executable JARs and JAVA files and I seem to remember they aren't what I need from past experience.

Comment: are you using an IDE?

Comment: The website of apache commons is quite resourceful. If you use maven add a dependency to apache commons-lang.

Comment: Yes I'm using Eclipse @Marco Bolis

Comment: I'm not using maven @wumpz

Comment: 1/ Add the bin jar to the build path and 2/ use the binary

Comment: I assume you mean the Exectuable JARs. I'll try that. Need to download 7zip first so I can extract. +1 for answering part 2.

Comment: You don't need to extract the jars. You just add them to your build path

Comment: hmm, added the complete zipped binary: I'm still getting this error: 'the import org.apache cannot be resolved'. Is my import statement incorrect?: `import org.apache.commons.lang.math.Fraction;`

Comment: Got it: should've been `import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction;`. Thanks all.

Comment: I couldn't get to the JARs without extracting @Marco Bolis

Comment: You are right, I mistakenly thought you were going to extract the jar's content! Sorry

Comment: No problems. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide to add `source` or `binary` to your eclipse `buildpath`, but i would always add just the complete `binary` to eclipse build path and if i need to see how the method internally really works we can any way have a look in the api source code without adding it to the buildpath.

Comment: +1 for useful info. hmm, added the complete zipped binary: I'm still getting this error: 'the import org.apache cannot be resolved'. Is my import statement incorrect?: `import org.apache.commons.lang.math.Fraction;`

Comment: You just need to add the `binary` not the zipped version (just the jar file)

Comment: Got it: should've been `import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction;`. Thanks.